# Método response en archivo Request de Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando redireccionar a otra pagina si falla la validación en mi archivo request.

Ya establecí

```
public function rules(){ ... ]
public function messages(){ ... }

public function response(array $errors){ ... }
```

Pero parece que no entra al response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establezca el nombre de su ruta como valor de la propiedad `$redirectRoute` en su `FormRequest`

```
protected $redirectRoute = 'errors'; // redireccionará a la ruta errors
```

si en esa ruta devuelve una vista , puede imprimir estos errores en la vista

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
    <h4>{{ $message }} </h4>
@endforeach
```